# Need response time and download time for the URLs and write shell scripts for same

Tags: linux, shell, curl

I have use command to get response time :

```
curl -s -w "%{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null https://www.ziffi.com/suggestadoc/js/ds.ziffi.https.v308.js
```

and I also need download time of this below mentioned js file link  so used wget command to download this file but i get multiple parameter out put. I just need download time from it

```
$ wget --output-document=/dev/null https://www.ziffi.com/suggestadoc/js/ds.ziffi.https.v307.js
```

please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
wget --output-document=/dev/null https://www.ziffi.com/suggestadoc/js/ds.ziffi.https.v307.js 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep = | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/^.*\=//'
```

Explanation:

**2>&1 >/dev/null |** --> Makes sure stderr gets piped instead of stdout

**grep =** --> select the line that contains the '=' symbol

**sed 's/^.*\=//'** --> deletes everything from linestart to the = symbol